# Improving PHP MYSQL Query Performance or Server Problem?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

**I have this query:**

```
SELECT
a.codigo AS code, a.nome AS name, a.especialidade AS expertise, a.telemovel1 AS mobile, a.email AS email, a.codigopostal AS zipcode
FROM table_name_a a
WHERE a.nome != ''
AND a.codigo!='5555555'
AND a.codigo!='705416'


UNION ALL

SELECT
b.cod AS code, b.nome AS name, b.especialidade AS expertise, b.telem1 AS mobile, b.mail AS email, b.cp AS zipcode
FROM table_name_b b
WHERE b.nome != ''
AND b.cod!='5555555'
AND b.cod!='705416'
AND b.cod NOT IN(SELECT assoc.codigo from table_name_a assoc) 

ORDER BY code ASC
```

**Table A:** +/-6000 rows *(and growing)*

**Table B:** +/-2000 rows *(and growing)*

**The problem:**

When the server is being used by one or two users doing several queries to the database, this query runs fine... but when the server is being used lets say during the day, with 10 users doing several queries and about +/- 1000 clients at any given hour performing some queries, the query goes from:

*Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 7,138 total, Query took 0.0734 sec)*

to

*Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 7,138 total, Query took 100.0933 sec)*

**Asking:**

Is this a query performance issue or the problem lies on the server configuration/performance ?

**EDITED:**

---

[image: tables indexes]

**Field Types:**

cod, codigo -> *int(11)*

nome, telemovel1, telem1, especialidade, codigopostal, cp -> *varchar(200)*

email -> *varchar(400)*

**EXPLAIN QUERIES:**

---

[image: Explain Question Query and Query From Karolis]

Comment: Without testing it I suppose the problem is in NOT IN clause.

Comment: Posting a question about query performance without giving details about column types and available indexes, suggests that you don't understand what your code is actually doing - thus it's probably a query/schema performance issue.

Comment: I've also had enormous loading times with NOT IN, so a rewrite is recommended.

Comment: @dor: I've updated the question to include what you've requested (honestly didn't had the time to build a proper question, sorry about that!)

Comment: Have you run an explain on the query to see where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offer you to rewrite this:

```
AND b.cod NOT IN (SELECT assoc.codigo from table_name_a assoc)
```

into this:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name_a assoc WHERE assoc.codigo = b.cod)
```

The rewritten query should use less memory leaving more of it for concurrent processes.

Comment: @Zuul Could you show an EXPLAIN output of your query and my query?

Comment: @Zuul But you said that my offering is slower than your original solution :)

Answer (score 0):

To try to find of how to optomise the query you should get the query plan. That will identify what indexes are used and how you can improve it. See the `EXPLAIN` keyword in MySql.

With that information in hand you can ensure that you have the correct indexes. Also you could consider temporary tables.